# HttpContext.Current.Session is null in OnPostAuthenticateRequest

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session

This is a n00b question, perhaps you can help.

When I'm in the `Application_OnPostAuthenticateRequest` event, I am unable to look into the `Session` since `HttpContext.Current.Session` is null.  Is there a reason that this is null, and is there a way I can access the `Session` during this event?

Is there an alternative event that allows me to get the authenticated user in addition to the session state?

Thanks!
Brett

Comment: Why are you looking at the session?

Comment: I have stored the authenticated user data in the session.

Comment: MVC is designed to be stateless.  Putting authentication data into the session is a poor practice.  Could you use a cookie instead?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot store it in a cookie.  Is there a way to get at the session or use another event?

Answer (score 1):

The `Session` won't be available before the [`PostAcquireRequestState` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.postacquirerequeststate%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) is raised.